# Listing all elements of a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I'm a bit confused as to what I'm supposed to be doing in the following introductory abstract algebra question.

I am asked to write all of the elements of $\mathbb{Z}^{x}_5$,$\mathbb{Z}^{x}_6$, $\mathbb{Z}^{x}_8$, and $\mathbb{Z}^{x}_{20}$

Is this as simple as writing out the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ under modular multiplication? I don't think that is the case as the result isn't a group.

So my other thought is that I would write out the 5th roots of unity?

That $\mathbb{Z}^{x}_5$={1,$e^{\frac{2\pi *i}{5}}$, $e^{\frac{4\pi *i}{5}}$, $e^{\frac{6\pi *i}{5}}$, $e^{\frac{8\pi *i}{5}}$}={1,$e^{\frac{2\pi *i}{5}}$, $e^{\frac{4\pi *i}{5}}$, $e^{-\frac{4\pi *i}{5}}$, $e^{-\frac{2\pi *i}{5}}$}

Am I on the right track with this?

Comment: They are asking for the *units* in those multiplicative structures. In $\mathbb{Z}_6^\times$ you would not list $2$, but you would list $5$.

Comment: Oh, so I am wrong in assuming that I am writing a multiplicative group with that number of integer elements? Or that I should be writing a cyclic group under complex multiplication? Could you give an example or point me to a resource that would confirm this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n

Comment: @Randall Thank you! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The set $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is the set of equivalence classes $\bar{a}$ which have multiplicative inverses mod $n$. Moreover $$\text{$(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}=\{\bar{a}\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\ \mid$ gcd $(a,n)=1$}\}.$$